# git submodule has uncommited change but inside module nothing is changed

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am not sure if I have followed the right procedure to set up my submodule. I think I initially did `git add url`, then `git submodule init` then `git submodule update`.

It seems that there is nothing in the submodule folder, then I find that the right command to do might be `git submodule update --init` which get me contents in submodule's folder, but in another situation, i still get nothing, so I went into the submodule's folder and executed `git pull origin master`, this time I got contents, but when i go back to the root project folder where the submodule lies in, I found when I run `git status`, there is uncommitted changes (but i did not change the submodule at all, I just pulled) something like  `modified:   submodule name (untracked content)`
, if I run `git checkout .`, the uncommitted changes does not disappear at all.

Anyone could show me what's wrong with the procedure and how should I solve the problem? (I do not want to have the uncommited changes since I did not change anything, and it seems that `git submodule update --init` does not work to get me the lastest commit from the submodule)

edit:
   If I go into the submodule folder and type

```
git log
```

I got

```
commit 268df2521e262d5ef1985db0e152cfd94542fe26 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
```

If I go to the parent repository folder, and type `git ls-tree -r -t HEAD | grep commit`, I got

```
160000 commit 268df2521e262d5ef1985db0e152cfd94542fe26
```

It seems that the two sha are the same?

Comment: A parent repository always tracks a certain commit of a submodule. If you change into the submodule and checkout another commit (as you apparently did), the parent repository will show the changed `HEAD` as a change of the submodule. If you add and commit the submodule, the current `HEAD` will be commited as the tracked commit.

Comment: is there a way to remove this commit from the parent repository? (i find git checkout . does nto work) since this commit does not make sense to me, i just pulled the content, but i did not change the submodule at all.

Comment: `git submodule update` will set the submodule to the commit it should have according to its' parent repository.

Comment: With `git ls-tree -r -t HEAD | grep commit`, you can see the submodule commit that has been tracked in `HEAD` of the main repository. If the submodule's current commit is not the tracked one, from the perspective of the main repo, its submodule is really changed.

Comment: @kowsky, git submodule update could not remove "modified:   submodule name (untracked content)"

Comment: @ElpieKay, it seems that the two commits are the same? see my edits